# Share data between containers using docker-compose and volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have following directory structure

```
.
├── core
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── requirements.txt
├── docker-compose.yaml
└── render
    ├── app.py
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── requirements.txt
```

Both the `Dockerfile`s contain following command

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-bullseye

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

For `docker-compose.yaml`,

```
version: '3'

services:
  core:
    build: ./core
    command:
      python app.py
    volumes:
      - "/data:/data:rw"

  render:
      build: ./render
      ports :
        - "8080:5000"
      command: 
        FLASK_APP=app.py flask run --host=0.0.0.0
      depends_on:
        - core
      volumes:
        - "/data:/data:ro"
```

Task:

1. I have a python script `app.py` in the `core` folder which basically generates a `.png` file inside `core` {Final path being `./core/data/ok.png`}.
2. Move this file to a docker volume
3. Access this file in python script `app.py` in the `render` folder and render it using a flask app.

Error:

```
WARNING: Image for service render was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Recreating docker_compose_core_1 ... error

ERROR: for docker_compose_core_1  no such image: sha256:9a401c01a3bf7ed346623e9e62ad8d064d17912daf9de9871dc47c88d74475ab: No such image: sha256:9a401c01a3bf7ed346623e9e62ad8d064d17912daf9de9871dc47c88d74475ab

ERROR: for core  no such image: sha256:9a401c01a3bf7ed346623e9e62ad8d064d17912daf9de9871dc47c88d74475ab: No such image: sha256:9a401c01a3bf7ed346623e9e62ad8d064d17912daf9de9871dc47c88d74475ab
ERROR: The image for the service you're trying to recreate has been removed. If you continue, volume data could be lost. Consider backing up your data before continuing.

Continue with the new image? [yN]ERROR: no such image: sha256:9a401c01a3bf7ed346623e9e62ad8d064d17912daf9de9871dc47c88d74475ab: No such image: sha256:9a401c01a3bf7ed346623e9e62ad8d064d17912daf9de9871dc47c88d74475ab
```

Please suggest corrections.

EDIT:

After removing all the images and containers, I ran the yaml file and got following.

```
WARNING: Image for service render was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating docker_compose_core_1 ... done
Creating docker_compose_render_1 ... error

ERROR: for docker_compose_render_1  Cannot start service render: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "FLASK_APP=app.py": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

ERROR: for render  Cannot start service render: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "FLASK_APP=app.py": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: If you're getting obscure `no such image` errors like that, you might try resetting your Docker installation (deleting `/var/lib/docker` on Linux, or using the "reset" button in a Docker Desktop installation).  You'll have to re-pull your images or rebuild them from source control.

Comment: @DavidMaze seems like something is wrong with the Flask's Environment variable. Isn't it?

Comment: You should set fixed environment variables like `FLASK_APP` using the Dockerfile `ENV` directive, and the standard container command using Dockerfile `CMD`.  You shouldn't usually need to override it with a Compose `command:` directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment variable for flask has to be fixed in the `yaml` file. Later when we call the command, we can use the placeholder for it in the following manner.

```
environment:
        - FLASK_APP=app.py

command: "${FLASK_APP} flask run --host=0.0.0.0"
```